# Is it possible to abort analysis if bytecode unavailable

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I am encountering a rather annoying situation where intermittently the surefire reports are not getting generated for some projects.  There are no errors in the log -

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default-test) @ nut-jar ---
[JENKINS] Recording test results
```

Perhaps related, the jar produced by the build does not contain any classes.

Later in the build, SonarQube gets invoked and because the jar does not have any classes, I get the "XXX is not accessible through the ClassLoader" warning.  Because there is no bytecode, any issues for the missing classes are being marked as fixed.  On a subsequent build, where the jar produced has the actual classes, all the "fixed" issues get redetected and new issues are opened.  This is causing havoc with tracking existing versus new issues.

Ultimately I need to find out why the class files are not being packaged into the jar.  But for now, I am hoping someone has an idea how I can abort SonarQube if it detects that bytecode is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Jenkins, I'd move analysis into a Conditional Build Step, and condition it on the existence of one of your `.class` files.